# Cancel a Table Update Event in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a case where I would like to catch an update event on a table, check what the current value is and what the new value would be for the affected column + row. If its not what is expected, I would like cancel the update and revert it back to what it was. This is incredibly hard to do with the TableModelListener and I keep running into stack overflow errors, because I am unable to manually maintain the state and revert it back without it recursively calling itself again.

Comment: When a TableModelEvent is fired, the data has already changed in the model. It's too late to cancel the event. You should cancel the edition of a cell to avoid the model from being changed.

Comment: I understand that JB, thats the reason why I was trying to manually maintain the state and the solution backfired. Which event do I have to catch in order to cancel the edition of the cell? And how do I cancel it? .. Thanks for helping..

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#validtext.

Comment: Thanks JB. I can see how to check whats being edited in that cell. But could you tell me how to get a handle to which row is being edited? I need to know the row because I need to put in a check based another coulumn's data. In the stopCellEditing() method how do I get the row that's being edited.

Comment: I think you'll have to set the row and column being edited in an instance variable of the editor when getCellEditorComponent is called, and use these variables in stopCellEditing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your own TableModel (or extend DefaultTableModel or AbstractTableModel), and override setValueAt - in there, you can either update the underlying model (with super.setValueAt()) or throw it away - you don't need to save the old value, because the change will never go through unless you call the superclass.

Comment: You might also be able to intercept things somewhere between editCellAt() and editingStopped(), but I think @Kylar has the simplest suggestion.